# How to animate an image above a listview when scrolling?

Tags: java, android, listview

I have an image above my listview that is currently doing nothing.But I want my image to be animated when the user scrolls in the listview just like
[this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8OC4.gif)

This is an example of an old library called `StikkyHeader` ,but it doesn't seem to work now.
Is there any other libraries for the same reason or even a way I can do it without libraries?

Comment: this is a [CoordinatorLayout scroll effect](https://guides.codepath.com/android/handling-scrolls-with-coordinatorlayout)

Comment: @Zain The thing is, can i do it without a toolbar?
I mean just an imageview and a textview?

Comment: Yes you can do it

Comment: @AgentP Can you please explain how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:minHeight="200dp"
        >



        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:minHeight="150dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="25dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/magic_bg"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.5"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:text="#KeepMakingMagic"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="-0.1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>



        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>



    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    <!-- You can have list view here Instead of scrollview But you need to make sure layout behaviour is same-->

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:layout_height="1000dp">


        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>



</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Demo :**
[image]

Don't forget to play with things

Comment: When i add the listview instead of the scrollview do i remove the linear layout insde?

Comment: Okay i added your code but when i scroll in my `gridview` (Not a listview actually) it does nothing it is only working when i touch and drag up on the image or text not while scrolling in gridview

Comment: Use gridview inside the NestedScrollView

Comment: Do i add the `layout_behavior` to both?

Comment: No only to the NestedScrollView

Comment: Okay it works but now only the first 2 items in my gridview are visible

Comment: Please search for that you will get it ... May be you need to setNestedScrollingEnabled I guess

Comment: When i set scrolling enabled it gives me a null pointer exception anyways i will go search for it thanks tho.
Just another quick question do you know how can i scale the image down when scrolling rather than just hiding part of it

Comment: I solved the gridview problem finally now do you know how can i scale the image down when scrolling rather than just hiding part of it ?

Comment: Well that would be tricky one... there is some listner to get the offset of collapsing toolbar you can use that and get the offset and based on that you can resize the image if needed but I have't tried it